# Firebase hosting location

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to use Firebase hosting rewrites config to use a Firebase function at Asia region. But I cannot find any document to do this.

Basically, I want to access my Firebase `app` function at the `asia-northeast1` region by  `https://<target-name>.firebaseapp.com/`.

What config (`firebase.json`) I'm trying:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "target": "my-target",
    "public": "public",
    "region": "asia-northeast1", // attempt #1
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "region": "asia-northeast1", // attempt #2
        "source": "**",
        "function": "app"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Jun 2019, this is impossible because Firebase Hosting is only available in `us-central1` region, thus can only proxy to Firebase Functions in the same region.

See [Firebase documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#connect_functions_to_hosting).

Comment: Sorry, seems I can't post my own answer on SuperUser. This has changed in 2022: https://firebase.blog/posts/2022/03/firebase-hosting-origin-servers-europe-asia/

Firebase now hosts content in Europe and Asia. You can use the format described in attempt #2. The newer, preferred, format is documented at https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrite-functions